# Search for list of values in string

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I want to search for several values in a text string and return the wanted value.

I tried the following:

```
=IF(COUNTIF($E$3:$E$14;"*"&A2&"*")>0;"found";"not")
```

However, within search I only can input one search value.

My sheet looks like the following:

[image]

Any suggestions, how to give the search function multiple values?

I appreciate your replies!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$3:$E$7,MATCH(TRUE,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$3:$E$7,A2)),0)),"Not Found")
```

Being an array formula it needs to be confirmed with Ctrl-Shift-Enter when exiting edit mode instead of Enter.  If done properly then Excel will put `{}` around the formula.

[image]

---

You will need to replace the `,` with `;` for your local requirements:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($E$3:$E$7;MATCH(TRUE;ISNUMBER(SEARCH($E$3:$E$7;A2));0));"Not Found")
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it also possible to search in A2 And C2 for example for values of E3 to E7?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: I have several strings(column A`s). I would like to search in multiple columns for a value of E. Any suggestions?

Comment: @mrquad try to manipulate the formula I gave.  If you are unable to do so please post a new question with data showing exactly what you mean.  I still am not understanding what you have and what you want, but it definitely is a new question.